# Special sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with a cluster point $a$. Does it converge to $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence which satisfies the following property:

$d(x_{n},x_{n+1}) \leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for all $n \geq 1$

Suppose that $a \in X$ is a cluster point of this particular sequence. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\{x_{n}\}=a$?

I have a feeling that it IS true, but I can't be sure. I've been trying to prove this. Here is my attempt:

Since $a$ is a cluster point of $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, we know that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $N\geq 1$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $d(x_{n}, a)< \epsilon$ (this is my definition of a cluster point).

Let us fix $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that $m \geq 1$ satisfies $\frac{1}{2^{m}}<\epsilon$. Then we have $d(x_{m}, x_{m+1})\leq\frac{1}{2^{m}}<\epsilon$. In fact for all $i,j \geq m$, we have $d(x_{i}, x_{j})<\epsilon$.

For this specific $m$, there exists some $n\geq m$ such that $d(x_{n}, a)<\epsilon$ (by definition of a cluster point).

For any $k \geq m$, we find that:

$d(x_{k},a) \geq d(x_{k},x_{n}) + d(x_{n},a) < 2 \epsilon$.

So we see that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $m\geq 1$ such that $d(x_{k}, a)<\epsilon$ for all $k \geq m$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\{x_{n}\}=a$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Leading question: If $\frac1{2^n}$  is replaced by $\frac1n$ does this still work?

Comment: @PVAL no because the sequence could be divergent

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this holds for any Cauchy sequence (the cluster point is a limit of a subsequence, etc.), and the distance condition implies that the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Mr (or Ms) HB has given the definitive answer, but the OP might not see it.  What you need to think about, for $m>n$, is that $$d(x_n,x_m)\leq d(x_n,x_{n+1}) + d(x_{n+1},x_{n+2}) + \dots + d(x_{m-1},x_m)$$ and remember how to work with the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}$.